# WordPress critical error on wp-admin page with 100% permissions

Tags: wp-admin, errors

I have such a problem. The site itself is fully working, but when I enter the site through the admin panel, it gives an error: "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.", but nothing comes to the mail. If you go to the admin panel with limited permissions, then there is no problem. Where to look for a problem? What can be wrong?

**Update:**
I have added to wp-config these lines, but it didn't helped.

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

Comment: Is there nothing in your PHP error log? What about the WP Debug log at `wp-content/debug.log`? ( assuming it's possible to write to that file )

Comment: Right now checked wp-content/debug.log, nothing about my problem. I have checked php logs, but there is nothing critical. I really don't know, how and where find that problem...

Comment: The problem is, the message you're recieving is just a generic something went wrong message, nobody can help you with the actual problem until you've discovered what the actual error message is. Try your servers PHP error logs, your host can advise you were to locate them

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and it turned out to be a php compatibility issue - I changed my site setting in my host’s cPanel from 8.1 to 8.0 and it resolved the issue.